# AWS Install SSL Certificate from Certificate Manager on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, aws-acm

I am using AWS and I created an Instance in EC2 and created a SSL Certificate in Certificate Manager, I have a domain from whois.com which I was able to connect to my instance using Route 53.

I am now trying to install the SSL Certificate to my EC2 instance and have googled a bunch on tutorials on the subject, but they all are super confusing and don't seem to work, must of them say I need to use a Load Balancer, but either I am missing a step or something I am doing is wrong because the SSL certificate is not working, http works like a charm, https is not working at all.

Is someone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

AWS do not allow the certificates to be downloaded for ACM public CA so you are limited with where it can be attached.

You **cannot** use a public ACM certificate directly in your EC2 instance. The following resources support attachment for HTTPS of your application:

- [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (ALB, CLB or Network Load Balancer with a TLS target group)
- [CloudFront Distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)
- [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)

If you do not want to use one of these resources then the following 3 options are available for you:

- Use a free SSL CA to generate the SSL for your EC2 instance such as [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)
- Purchase a SSL from another CA and install on your host
- Use [AWS ACM Private CA](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/) (Although this can be expensive)

Comment: By using Elastic Load Balancer, can I connect the SSL certificate to my EC2 instance? Do I have to do anything on the ubuntu server in my instance?

Comment: By adding an ELB, you would set your instance as a target. The load balancer could serve SSL with the instance still running HTTP (this is known as SSL termination). This would require no changes on the instance itself.